# Canvas Resize error with jQuery TimeCircles

Tags: jquery, resize

I'm using *jQuery TimeCircles* plugin . 
When I'm resizing the page , the CountDown div don't change his width unless i'm refreshing the page . How can I fix this problem ?

Demo: http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `window.onresize` event and then rebuild the TimeCircles. Something similar to:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    $(".example").TimeCircles().rebuild(); 
};
```

(after: http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php#func_rebuild)